# How to reload a value in only one row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am have a table and there are some data in tables, and i have a refresh button in the last column of every row.

what i want is when i click some refresh button in some row only that row should get reloaded.

but now what is happening is when i click the refresh button every row is getting reloaded,,,

How can this?

Here is the code i have used:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(".b1").load("content.txt");
    $(".b2").load("content1.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<table border="1">
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
<tr><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="b1"></td><td class="b2"></td><td class="buto"><button>Refresh</button></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `this` reference

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".b1").load("content.txt");
  $(this).parents('tr').find(".b2").load("content1.txt");
});
```

or

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings(".b1").load("content.txt");
  $(this).parent().siblings(".b2").load("content1.txt");
});
```

Comment: `.closest()` won't work from the button as it looks only through ancestor elements.

Comment: But when i change in text file and click refresh, it is not getting updated... Why?

Comment: There is the possibility that the results are caching.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".b1")` and `$(".b2")` are selecting every element with that class. You need to filter based on the row the button is in using something like this:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $row.find(".b1").load("content.txt");
    $row.find(".b2").load("content1.txt");
});
```