# Table does not disappear on AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to remove to this table on successful delete from an AJAX to PHP call.

Below is the function ,

**list.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function massDelete()
    {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure"))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            var selecedids = $("#selectedids").val();
            {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("success").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_delete.php?massDelete=" + selectedids.value, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

the above code successfully gives me the selected ID for deletion

on this PHP side which is on another File

**ajax_delete.php**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_REQUEST['massDelete'])) {

    $selectId = $_REQUEST['massDelete'];
    $finalId = ltrim($selectId, ",");

    $sql = mysql_query("delete from contact_form where contactUser_id in ($finalId)", $con);
    if ($sql) {
        // echo '<script>';
        //echo 'var parent = document.getElementById("fullTable")';
        //echo 'element.remove(parent)';
        //echo '</script>';
        echo "sucess deleted";
    } else {
        echo "Please select a Contact to delete";
    }
}
?>
```

The response does give me the successful message, but somewhere I want to disappear the below HTML table in response

**list.php**

```
<?php

echo '<table id="fullTable">';
echo "<tr><td> ";
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="checkAll"/></td>';
echo '<td colspan="8" align="right">';
echo '<button type="submit" onClick="return massDelete()" name="delete" class="deleteall" id="deleted">Delete All</button></td>';
echo "</tr>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>FIRST NAME</th>
<th>LAST NAME</th>
<th>EMAIL</th>
<th>PHONE</th>
<th>FAX</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo '<div id="checkboxlist">';
    echo '<tr class="show">';
    echo '<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" value="' . $row['contactUser_id'] . '" id="Checkbox1"></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['first_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['last_name'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['email'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['phone'] . '</th>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['fax'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="addedit.php?id=' . $row['contactUser_id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a class="delete" href="#" id="' . $row['contactUser_id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
    echo '<td><a href="view.php?id=' . $row['contactUser_id'] . '" target="_blank">View</a></td>';
    echo '</div>';
}

} else {
    echo '<td colspan="9"><h1>No contacts found.</td></h1>';
}
?>
```

I am confused to what should I do so that if one row is deleted than only that row disappears,

[image]

but if all the checkboxes are selected for deletion, than on sucess, tha whole table should disappear..

[image]

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Yes I know I should be using `mysqli` instead but the above program is just for conceptual purpose. @SLaks

Comment: Just to confirm I'm not stupid - your code currently doesn't delete any rows?

Comment: it does, but the thing is I have to refresh the page.. But while calling an AJAX why would I like to refresh a page instead when I can do already with simple PHP.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like the php successfully deletes it since when you refresh the page the correct data shows up.

But if the page has to be refreshed for it to show up properly, you need to make sure you are returning the correct information, and parsing it correctly. Just `console.log()` the response `xhttp.responseText`, and see if the correct data is returned, and then double check you are parsing it correctly (changing the dom appropriately).

Comment: I have done that. Correct value has been passed through AJAX function and PHP does delete those information passed from this function. What I did not mentioned here is that (which I will correct it now) the PHP code lies in another file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to refresh your page to show it's correct.  You need to use javascript to remove the row on success.  Here's the basics:

```
var deletedRow = $('#fullTable');
$.post('script.php', {data:data}, function(){
    if(data == "success"){
        deletedRow.remove(); //This will remove the row from the view
    }
});
```

Ajax can return a call and you give a statement that shows if success, you have to have javascript actually delete it.  Yes, we know it's removed from the database, so you can successfully remove the view from the page.

**UPDATE** This is using jQuery, not pure javascript.  But it's only an example to show that you need to delete the element using javascript and it won't just disappear because it's not in your database anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after referring to this [remove any element using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972986/how-to-reload-a-value-in-only-one-row-of-table)

I found the solution, and I also changed the AJAX function code which is mentioned below,

function massDelete()
         {

```
     var element = $(this);
     var selecedids = $("#selectedids").val();
     var info = 'massDelete=' + selectedids.value;
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?"))
     {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_delete.php",
        data: info,
        success: function(){
      }
     });
     $this.parent("#fullTable").load("list.php");

      }
     return false;
     }
```

the      `$this.parent("#fullTable").load("list.php");`  statement reloaded that table hence reflecting only those information which are present in the database.